# invalid PKCS #7 block padding found in file decryption

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I am working on a project that includes encrypting and decrypting files, I process the file and then I encrypt it and save it on a new file with a custom file extension, the file includes the encrypted file bytes and the IV used during encryption, like this: IV#fileBytes.
When decrypting the file I encounter the problem "invalid PKCS #7 block padding found in file decryption".  I will really appreciate some help, Thank you!

```
void encryptFile(const byte* AESkey, const std::string& path)
{
    
    std::ifstream binaryFile;
    std::ofstream encryptedFile;
    std::string encryptedDataBinary;

    binaryFile.open(path, std::ios::binary);
    encryptedFile.open(path + ".lok", std::ios::binary);

    // Initialize with a random IV
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock iv(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE); 
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());
    

    // Write the IV as raw bytes to the beginning of the encrypted file
    encryptedFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(iv.data()), iv.size());
    encryptedFile << '#'; // Add the separator


    // Create AES encryption object
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(AESkey, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv);


    // Read the entire file
    std::string inputData(
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(binaryFile)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    );       


    // Encrypt the data
    // The StreamTransformationFilter adds padding
    //  as required. ECB and CBC Mode must be padded
    //  to the block size of the cipher.
    CryptoPP::StringSource(inputData, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(e, new      CryptoPP::StringSink(encryptedDataBinary)));


    encryptedFile << encryptedDataBinary;

    // Close the files
    binaryFile.close();
    encryptedFile.close();
    std::remove(path.c_str());`
}
```

```
void decryptFile(const byte* AESkey, std::string& path)
{
    std::string decrypted;
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock iv(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    std::fstream decryptedFile;
    std::ifstream encryptedFile;
    std::stringstream inputData;

    decryptedFile.open(revertFileExtension(path), std::ios::binary);
    encryptedFile.open(path);

    // Read the IV from the beginning of the encrypted file
    encryptedFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(iv.data()), iv.size());

    encryptedFile.rdstate();

    // Skip the "#" separator
    char separator;
    encryptedFile.read(&separator, 1);

    // Process the rest of the file (excluding the IV and separator)
    inputData << encryptedFile.rdbuf();
    
    //decoding hex data to just aes encrypted

    //decrypting aes
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Decryption d;
    d.SetKeyWithIV(AESkey, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv);


    // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
    //padding as required.
    CryptoPP::StringSource ssd(inputData.str(), true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(d, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decrypted)));

    decryptedFile << decrypted;

    // Close the files
    encryptedFile.close();
    decryptedFile.close();

    // Remove the original encrypted file
    std::remove(path.c_str());`
}
```

I tested the code on .txt files, I checked the key the IV and the encrypted file bytes and didn't notice any change that was caused because of saving them on the new file.

Comment: In `decryptFile()` try to open the encrypted file in `std::ios::binary` mode.

Comment: when I do so I get an error when opening the file, rdstate() returns 2.